# marquee tag is not applying to textview in hdpi devices but working in xhdpi devices in android

Tags: android

Below is the code for textview. This marquee tag is working in large devices but not working in hdpi and mdpi devices.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_country_name"
    android:layout_width="?attr/country_name_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="?clock_city_text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normaltxtsize" />
```

Comment: First of all marquee is not depend device size.

Comment: Do you created more than "layout" folder (layout, layout-land, etc...)?

Comment: k, marquee tag is working in gridview and not working in listview in hdpi devices.I applied same code for both the views.is there any feature to add to listview?

Comment: yes i have created both layout and layout-land folders